# IOException when creating a temporary file?

Tags: java, ioexception, bamboo, temporary-files

I'm creating a task plugin for Atlassian Bamboo. At some moment of task executing, I would like to create a temporary file:

```
File temp = File.createTempFile(fileName.toString(), null, dir);
temp.deleteOnExit();
```

, where:

```
fileName.toString() = e.g. "C:\Atlassian\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\CMPT-CMPTP-JOB1\test.java"
dir = new File("temp");
```

When testing this locally, everything works fine - the file is created properly. However, after I deploy plugin on server and try to execute above code, I've got an IOException:

```
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
        at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)
```

What could be the reason?

Additional info: I'm pretty sure that `dir.exists()` .

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131901/what-are-possible-reasons-for-java-io-ioexception-the-filename-directory-name

Comment: I've already seen this question and I' ve checked first three answers. Still no results.

Comment: Is your server a Unix box? If so, the C:/... isn't valid

Comment: What a curious prefix for your temp file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file name of

```
"C:\Atlassian\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\CMPT-CMPTP-JOB1\test.java"
```

is valid on Windows but is invalid on Unix operating systems. You won't be able to create a (temp) file like that, either as specified as the absolute name/path or the file nor just relative to another folder.

If your OS is Windows, you still can't use a full path (starting with drive specification like `"C:"`) to be created as a child of another folder.

Comment: Both my local computer and server are on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could have spaces in the beginning or the ending of your path, print your  `file.getAbsolutePath()` in order to see the current path where java is reading.

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` variable must be set with the full (or relative) path to the directory `temp`. The first arg of `File.createTempFile` should be the prefix of the temp file (at least three letter long. for exeample "test"). This will create a "test.tmp" in the given directory (specified by the variable `dir`).

Check [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can check existence of the directory `dir` with `dir.exists()`

Comment: I guess because the file structure of your computer is different from the one on the server. To avoid this kind of issue, try to use only relative path (for example: "./temp" will always refer to the directory "temp" located in the execution folder, not matter if running on computer or server)

Comment: The spec said that value could be no related to the temp folder "If the directory argument is null then the system-dependent default temporary-file directory will be used"