# I Cant Clear The Error! Please Any one Sort it Out

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

`

```
package Xcel;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class NewTest {
  @Test
  public void f() throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException 
  {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\New Folder\\chromedriver.exe");
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

      driver.get("http://127.0.0.1/login.do");

      String un = NewTest.afterMethod(1, 0);

      driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(un);

      String ur = NewTest.afterMethod(1, 1);

      driver.findElement(By.name("pwd")).sendKeys(ur);

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();



  }

 public static String afterMethod(int r, int c) throwsEncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException 
  {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("‪E:\\Test\\Book1.xlsx");

      Workbook Wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);

      String s1 = Wb.getSheet("Test1").getRow(r).getCell(c).getStringCellValue();

      return s1;
  }


}
```

`I Have Gave All The Test Script Correctly . But Still Am Getting an Error . The Error is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ?E:\Test\Book1.xlsx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. [[Error screen shot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WSMO.jpg)

and Finally HTML Code is,

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="" style="width: 213px"> - Username 
<input type="password" name="pwd" value="" style="width: 213px">- Password
<input type="submit" valign="absmiddle" value="&nbsp;Login now&nbsp;">- Login Now Button
```

Comment: I you have hide the extension of files, make sure the file is `xlsx` not `xls`

Comment: Please attach your code and full error stack, rather than just a screenshot. It seems the error has nothing to do with Selenium, but with the `FileInputStream`

Comment: I Have Attached All The Code Please Help Me To Sort it Out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are getting : `Java.io.FileNotFoundException: ?E:\Test\Book1.xlsx (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`  has nothing to do with **selenium** , it is because your binding language in your case it is JAVA.

**Suggestion 1**:

Use try catch block :

```
try
    { 
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("‪E:\\Test\\Book1.xlsx"); 
    } 
catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("File error !!!"); 
    }
```

**Suggestion 2:**

It takes more care of adjusting directory separator characters in the path between targetPath and filename:

```
File targetFile = new File(targetPath, filename);
```

**Suggestion 3 :**

Most of the people have encountered this issue because of access permission. Just make sure your code is able to read/write the xlsx file.

I have got some of the reference , may be they will help you better :

[Java file exception SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131901/what-are-possible-reasons-for-java-io-ioexception-the-filename-directory-name)
[Java file exception github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cucumber-reports-plugin/issues/155)

Comment: Suggestion 2:

It takes more care of adjusting directory separator characters in the path between targetPath and filename:

File targetFile = new File(targetPath, filename);

Thanks a Lot Suggestion 2 Helped Me. Please Be in Touch  Man!