# Java/Webdav: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect”

Tags: java, url, java-io, webdav

I know this might be a simple one, but I can't solve it.

I am trying to upload a file from Java client to webdav server and this is my code snippet

```
String filename = "abc.csv";
File targetFolder = new File("https://webdavserverurl/Uploads/");
File targetFile = new File(targetFolder, filename);
.....http connections stuffs
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToCopy);
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile); // exception here
byte[] buffer = new byte[64*1024];
            int i = 0;
            while((i = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, i);
            }
```

While creating the o/p stream, I'm getting

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:\webdavserverurl\Uploads\abc.csv
> (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Why it changing the path and how can I fix it ?

Note:

1. It is a `PUT` request. The file abc.csv is getting created in the server location ( I can see in web interface). But the file is empty for obvious reason.
2. The user has all the credential.
3. The file size is less than 1 Mb.
4. I can put the file manually in the location with the credential.
5. I have tried everything suggested here already: [What are possible reasons for java.io.IOException: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131901/what-are-possible-reasons-for-java-io-ioexception-the-filename-directory-name)

Comment: You must use `java.net.URL` as a pointer to a file in the world wide web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*to read a file from an URL:*

```
try {
  URL url = new URL("https://webdavserverurl/Uploads/abc.csv");    
  try( InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
      BufferedReader brd = new BufferedReader( isr ); ) {
  }
  catch( IOException ex ) {…}
}
catch( MalformedURLException ex ) {…}
```